# ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use

Tags: sql, database, mariadb, mysql-error-1064

I am new to Database I am having this Error
I am using MariaDB

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'hotel_name varchar(20),
city varchar(10)
)' at line 3

another error
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

Comment: Please post code not images of code

Comment: `number` is not a supported type.  Identifiers (like column names) are restricted, but you can include characters like `#` if you quote the identifier (backtick or double quotes, depending on the sql_mode).  Try to avoid using special characters where possible.

Comment: this # character is given in the task I can't avoid to use it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `#` character is a comment character. Any characters following that comment until the end of the line is ignored. Read https://mariadb.com/kb/en/comment-syntax/

So this:

```
create table hotel(
  hotel# number(10),
  hotel_name varchar(10)
  ...
```

appears to the SQL parser as:

```
create table hotel(
  hotel
  hotel_name varchar(10)
  ...
```

This is missing a data type and a comma after the column `hotel`.

You can use special symbols like punctuation characters in your column names if you delimit them with back-ticks like this:

```
  `hotel#` int,
```

(Also use `int` not `number` because the latter is not a data type supported by MariaDB.)

But you would have to remember to use the back-ticks every time you reference that column in any query. It's simpler if you just avoid using special characters if you can.

This is easier:

```
  hotel_num int,
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue may be related to your use of "number(10)". That is not a valid MariaDB datatype. See the MariaDB datatypes here: https://www.mariadbtutorial.com/mariadb-basics/mariadb-data-types/

EDIT:
MariaDB also does not allow # in identifier names. See the valid identifier names here: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/identifier-names/

Comment: I checked but it not workin

Comment: ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

Comment: Here is the another error

Comment: The # you used is also an issue. See the valid identifier names: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/identifier-names/